# Отправка массива POST запросом в адресной строке

Tags: javascript, post, request

Есть кусок кода на js который работает отлично:

```js
{
  fields: {
    "NAME": "Иванов Иван",
    "TYPE_ID": "CLIENT",
    "PHONE": [{
      "VALUE": "5555555",
      "VALUE_TYPE": "WORK"
    }]
  }
}
```

Пытаюсь отправить post запрос через адресную строку:

```
https://adress.to.site.api/api.method?fields[NAME]=Иванов%20Иван&fields[TYPE_ID]=CLIENT&fields[PHONE[VALUE_TYPE]=WORK,%20PHONE[VALUE]=5555555]
```

Запрос уходит, ошибок нет, запись добавляется, только поле PHONE пустое. Где я не прав?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, адресная строка отправляет только get запрос, попробуйте использовать для post запроса программу postman

Comment: благодарю за наводку!